# how to calculate degree centrality of complex network in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to calculate degree centrality of each node in a small-world network using NetLogo tool. I'm using network extension "nw". I calculated closeness, betweenness and eigne vector easily using this extension.

but I don't know how to code for degree centrality. Any help plz.

Comment: degree centrality is the same as degree, or the number of links (edges) it has. Counting links is part of standard NetLogo rather than the nw extension.